# django unable to hide button

Tags: html, django

I have a html file in django.
I want to show a button if a specific condition is met otherwise simply not show it.

This is the relevant code:

`urls.py`:

```
url(r'^hellos/(?P<id>.*)/$', hello, name = hello),
```

`views.py`:

```
def hello(request, id):
   ....
   try:
        a = ItemHello.objects.get(idx = int(id))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
   alreadyfilled = False
   if a.check_alreadyfilled():
     print alreadyfilled 
     alreadyfilled = True
```

`models.py`:

```
class ItemHello(models.Model):
    idx= models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    answered = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    ...
    def check_alreadyfilled(self):
        if self.answered:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

`hello.html`:

```
<tr>
        <td>{% if not alreadyfilled %}<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="doSubmit();" />{% endif %}</td>
</tr>
```

However this doesn't work.

the alreadyfilled gets the correct values. I checked the print of `alreadyfilled`  in `views.py` it gives `true` and `false` correctly, However for some readon hello.html always claim that `{% if not alreadyfilled %}` is true and shows me the button.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to send `alreadyfilled` parameter in the context of the template.**

Since you are not sending this variable, the template always displays the button.

You can create a `context` dict and pass the `context` when rendering the template. This will then pass the variable `alreadyfilled` into the template.

```
def hello(request, id):
   ....
   try:
        a = ItemHello.objects.get(idx = int(id))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
   alreadyfilled = False
   if a.check_alreadyfilled():
     print alreadyfilled 
     alreadyfilled = True
   ...
   context = {'alreadyfilled': alreadyfilled} # pass the parameter in the context
   return render(request, 'template_name.html', context)
```